# ld: library not found for -lGL Error

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glut

In OSX, I'm working on assignment where I was asked to run make file, when I do that, I ended up with this error:[image]
ld: library not found for -lGL

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I've installed `glew` and `glfw3` in my OS.
Can someone help me with this.

I found few similar questions but didn't get required answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you use cmake, you can just `find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)` and it will "do the right thing"  https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/module/FindOpenGL.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When using OpenGL on MacOS, one has to replace `-lGL` with `-framework OpenGL`. Same goes for glut. The command should look somehow like this:

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include 01_triangle.cpp gl_framework.cpp shader_util.cpp -o 01_triangle -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT
```

Also note, that some include pathes are different on OSX. For example, the Windows/Linux includes

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
```

has to be replaced with

```
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
```